# Is there a service that will call a webhook when a transaction occurs with an eth wallet

Tags: ethereum, webhooks

I am wondering if there are any services or websites that will automatically monitor an Ethereum wallet and when a transaction occurs with it (either in or out) it calls a specified web hook?

Answer (score 0):

Defender Sentinel from Openzeppelin monitors function calls and events on contracts and can trigger webhooks, emails, slack ect.
It doesn't seem to work on non-contract addresses though.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/sentinel

Alchemy Notify seems to be able to do that with non-contract addresses.

https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/using-notify